# change json field name jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to change the name of the field:

```
public class Track {

@JsonProperty("title2")
private String title;
...}
```

And I've got the method:

```
@Path("/json/metallica")
public class MyRest {

@GET
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Track getTrackInJSON() {

    Track track = new Track();
    track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
    track.setSinger("Metallica");

    return track;

}
```

After calling the method I expect to see

```
{"singer":"Metallica","title2":"Enter Sandman"}
```

But there is:

```
{"singer":"Metallica","title":"Enter Sandman"}
```

What am I doing wrong?.. It seems that it should work...

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using for the annotations? What version of Jackson are you using for the serialization?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis
jackson-annotations - 2.5.3,
jackson-core - 2.5.3,
jersey-client - 1.8

Comment: Double-check your classpath. It seems to me like you're using `com.fasterxml` (Jackson 2) for annotations and Jackson 1 for serializing.

Comment: I'm just using the following dependencies:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client/1.8
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.5.3
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.5.3